# Wells are exceeding the row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm trying to put 3 Wells in one row, like this

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">

    <div class="span4 well">
        <h3 class="centralizado"><img src="/assets/temple.png" />
            <a href="<%= ministerios_path %>" class="no-style">Ministérios</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Aqui vai um texto meio longo, mas eu acho que nao vai ultrapassar o well</p>
    </div>

    <div class="span4 well">
        <h3 class="centralizado"><img src="/assets/educacao.png" />
            <a href="<%= educacionais_path %>" class="no-style">Educaional</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Aqui vai um texto meio longo, mas eu acho que nao vai ultrapassar o well</p>
    </div>

    <div class="span4 well">
        <h3 class="centralizado"><img src="/assets/contato.png" />
            <a href="/contato" class="no-style">Contato</a>
        </h3>
        <p>Aqui vai um texto meio longo, mas eu acho que nao vai ultrapassar o well</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

But this is the output:
[image: wells]

The 3 Wells should be in the same row. I'm using `container`, not `container-fluid`.

This is the customized css:

```
.well{
    background-color: white !important;
}

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: Probably not enought place for third div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `Well` style adds extra padding and margins which are not taken into account by the `span`s. Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JU4bZ/).

The easiest solution is to add box-sizing model:

```
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
```

[Here's good info](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) on the box-sizing model.

---

**Edit:** Tested in [Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my0JP.png), [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtPCW.png), [IE 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N89yt.png), [9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWMT5.png) and [10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qyO5.png)

Comment: @soyuka Yes sir, tested on IE8, 9 and 10.

Comment: I'm on OSx and can't test on IE, but when I deploy, I will know it :)

Comment: Make sure you do testing on your end, and come back if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Just set another div inside the span :

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px">
    <div class="span4">
        <div class="well">
            <h3 class="centralizado"><img src="/assets/temple.png" />
                <a href="<%= ministerios_path %>" class="no-style">Ministérios</a>
            </h3>
            <p>Aqui vai um texto meio longo, mas eu acho que nao vai ultrapassar o well</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

As you can see in the `bootstrap.css`, the `well` class has it's own `border` and `padding` which makes the `div.span4` to take more width than it should.